# Mask url with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I looked on the web but none of the questions had condition similar to mine.

I want to rewrite `http://sub.domain.com/this` to `http://domain.com` essentially masking the url
For example, if a user goes to `http://domain.com` he should see content of `http://sub.domain.com/this` and i want to accomplish this without redirect (so the url remains same)

Is it possible? Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You just have to put this `.htaccess` in your root folder :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://sub.domain.com/this [L]
```

Comment: Oh, right. That's because it's not the same domain. Can you try to enable Apache's `mod_proxy` and use `[L,P]` tags instead of `[L]` ?